FastAPI and unclosed connection
I have a FastAPI app which (for some reason) throws a lot (!) of warnings
ResourceWarning: unclosed connection <asyncpg.connection.Connection object at 0x>
and
unclosed resource <TCPTransport closed=False reading=False 0x5a17c850d000>
I have checked that everywhere I do some kind of database manipulation i.e load models/write models etc. is within a context-manager i.e
 with create_session() as session:
        session.add(db_models)
        session.commit()

and
    query = select(model.source_identifier).filter(model.source_identifier == id_to_check,
                                                   model.data["embedding_model"].astext==CURRENT_EMBEDDING_MODEL.value)
    async with create_async_session() as session:
        row = await session.execute(query)
        row_exists = bool(row.scalar())
    return row_exists

where create_async_session is
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession, AsyncEngine, async_sessionmaker

def _create_async_engine() -> AsyncEngine:
    hostname = os.environ.get('Postgres__Hostname')
    username = os.environ.get('Postgres__Username')
    password = os.environ.get('Postgres__Password')
    database_name = os.environ.get('Postgres__Name')
    return create_async_engine(
        f"postgresql+asyncpg://{username}:{password}@{hostname}/{database_name}"
    )

_asyncsessionmaker = async_sessionmaker()
_asyncsessionmaker.configure(bind=_create_async_engine())

def create_async_session() -> AsyncSession:
    return _asyncsessionmaker()

thus I simply cannot figure it out what else it should be.
It seems to be rather random and come in chunks - it is not like after each request it comes.
